# PythonでPDFでの日本語表示について

Tags: python

Pythonで日本語のMarkdownファイルをPDFに吐き出すコードを書いてるのですが日本語ファイルだと文字化けしてしまってうまく行きません誰かおしえてもらえると嬉しいです。
ソールコードはこれです。

```
#coding utf-8
import markdown
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPrinter
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
printer = QPrinter()

def load_finished():
    global web
    global printer

    web.print_(printer)
    QApplication.exit()

def md2html(_fileName):
    md=markdown.Markdown()
    tmpText = u'<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"></head><body>' 
    text=""
    for i in open(_fileName,"r"):
         text+=unicode(i,'utf-8')

    text=md.convert(text)
    tmpText+=text+u"</body></html>"
    fn=open("test.html","w")
    fn.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
    fn.close()

def html2pdf():
    global app
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Landscape)
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setResolution(QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setOutputFileName('test.pdf')

    web.loadFinished.connect(load_finished)
    web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath('test.html')))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())




md2html("aaa.md")
html2pdf()
```

まだ文字コードらへんについてわかってない点も多いのでアドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
PDFはこんな感じです。
実際には「テスト」と表示させたいです。

Answer (score 4):

ここのコードだけ見ると、tmpTextの内容が出力に反映されていなさそうです。
tmpTextに文字コード指定を入れているようなので、これが原因かもしれないですね。
確認して見て下さい。

```
tmpText+=text+"</body></html>"
fn=open("test.html","w")
fn.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: うーんここを修正すると
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-6: ordinal not in range(128)
とエラーが出てしまいます…

というかどう修正するのがいいのかわかりません。すいません

Comment: tmpTextに、textと閉じタグを足しているのですが、その後にwriteしているのはtextなので、tmpTextが出力に反映されていないのでは？と思った次第です。

Comment: ！！！！！
これは凡ミスでした！！
動きましたありがとうございます！